# отладка зависающего приложения VS

Tags: c#, unity3d, отладка

В *Unity* зависает редактор. Если сбилдить программу(под вин), то она тоже зависает(no responding). Не могу найти причину: выполняю неопределенное количество раз одно и тоже действие и потом зависание. Поставить `breakpoint` не могу потому, что не ясно где их ставить. Мне кажется, что зависает где-то  в скриптах юнити.

Как можно получить место в котором программа зависает? Можно ли посмотреть какой то журнал где выписаны все действия программы? Я думаю что где-то получается бесконечный цикл, хотя я все циклы проверил...

Спасибо!

Comment: А MonoDevelop есть? Теоретически должно работать форсированный break.... а-ля https://youtu.be/X8aw1n1ZJQo

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский , Да в MonoDevelop  действительно удобно просматривать стек вызовов. В студии  почему то так не получается. Проблему решил, спасибо!

Comment: по идее  у студии тоже есть `break all`, который тоже должен останавливать в месте зависания....но чет не всё так просто видимо там.........в итоге через моно схватилось?  а то, что в блоге в первой ссылке написано не пробовали?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский , пробовал, но там не читабельно.

Comment: Всё. Теперь будет читабельно (я думаю). Специально перенес всё в ответ. Думаю это будет нужная и важная штука тут

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Есть минимум три решения (если есть другие — дайте знать): два быстрых и одно долгое. Причем долгое связанно именно с *Visual Studio* (почему у *Microsoft* не может быть всё просто?)

---

### Наибыстрейшее (но материально затратное)

Нужно пойти в *UnityAssetStore* и найти ассет (asset) под названием *Panic Button*. Он находится в разделе *Editor Extensions/System*. На данный момент этот ассет находится **[вот здесь](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/40167)**.

Что он делает? Когда приложение крутится в бесконечном цикле и интерфейс *Unity* висит, достаточно нажать клавиши <kbd>Shift + Esc</kbd> и происходит "обрыв" главного потока, интерфейс отвисает. При этом проигрывание ставится на паузу, а в консоли отображается проблемное место:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как конкретно она работает? Что происходит внутри? Скорее всего то, что будет описано в пункте №3, только сделанное в виде скрипта, упакованного в dll (чтоб никто не видел код ), подключаемую к проекту.

---

### Использовать *MonoDevelop*

Шаги следующие:

- Пишем скрипт с бесконечным циклом, вешаем на объект и нажимаем `Play` :-)
- Идем в *MonoDevelop* и нажимаем `Run` → `Attach To Process`

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- В появившемся окне выбираем *Unity* и нажимаем `Attach`

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Нажимаем кнопку `Pause` в *MonoDevelop*

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Mono уже остановится в проблемном месте и высветится `StackTrace`

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Остается теперь поставить `Breakpoint` на строку, изменить значение, которое вводит в бесконечный цикл (в данном случае присвоить i значение 20, например) и нажать `Continue Execution`

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Вздохнуть с облегчением.

---

### Использовать *Visual Studio*

Шаги:

- Пишем скрипт с бесконечным циклом, вешаем на объект и нажимаем `Play` :-)

  Например скрипт такой:

  ```
  using UnityEngine;
  public class Quicksand : MonoBehaviour {
     void OnMouseDown()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             // "Mind you, you'll keep sinking forever!!", -- My mom
         }
     }
  }
  ```
- Идем в *Visual Studio*, нажимаем в меню `Debug` → `Attach to Process` и выбираем в списке процессов *Unity*.

  **Заметка (!)**: Именно `Attach to Process`, а **НЕ** `Attach To Unity`

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Далее нажимаем `Debug` → `Break all`, чтоб остановить процесс
- Нужно найти дизассемблированный вид (если он автоматически не появился). В теории на вкладке StackTrace если нажать два раза <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>, то появится окно, в котором можно нажать ссылку *view disassembly*

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  И через стэк попасть в место зависания. Анимация ниже должна полностью показать, как пробраться туда:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- В итоге получаем примерно следующую картину:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  Из него практически видно бесконечный цикл.

  В реальности код может быть сложнее и будет трудно быстро разобрать, что там происходит, но сильно можно не вникать, ибо есть небольшой трюк (см. следующий шаг):
- <kbd>F10</kbd> - сделать шаг в отладке, не заходя в функцию/метод. Соответственно, теперь пошагово нажимаем <kbd>F10</kbd>, пока не перелетим со строки `000000001015A758 jmp 000000001015A743` на строку с инструкцией `cmp dword ptr [r11], 0`.

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  В итоге во вкладке `Autos` в *Visual Studio* должны появится данные значения:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Теперь просто меняем значение "переменной" R11 на ноль (0)

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Так как мы стоим на адресе `cmp`, то при попытки исполнить инструкцию, она попытается прочитать address  0, что, в свою очередь, сгенерирует ошибку. Что мы делаем: Нажимаем <kbd>F5</kbd> (продолжить выполнение программы), а затем во всплывающем окне выбираем `Continue`.

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- В теории, *Unity* должна ожить и плюнуть в консоль ошибку, указав, где была загвоздка:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Вздохнуть с облегчением.

---

P.S. Способ с *Visual Studio* был позаимствован в **[блоге Unity](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2016/05/24/breakout-how-to-stop-an-infinite-loop-in-a-unity-c-script/)**. Там же можно прочитать, почему способ работает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как же много букафф

Comment: Спасибо, я старался %)

Comment: Отличный ответ, а Вы не могли бы пояснить,  почему именно `Attach to Process`, а НЕ `Attach To Unity`? :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov Это видимо связано с механикой работы самого VS. Потому, что  через `Attach to Process` мы можем приаттачиться вообще к любому активному процессу в винде и поотлаживать. Например, когда программа падает и появляется окно об отладке - можно в VS с этим поработать...То есть некая тонкая отладка и, как раз-таки работа с дисассемблированным кодом. В `Attach To Unity` вроде такого нет.

Comment: Я просто не видел `Attach To Unity`, пользуюсь `Attach to Process` обычно :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov а у меня никогда он толком не работал. Поэтому раньше юзал `VS Tools for unity` от `syntaxTree`, которые специально для дебага под юнити делали плагин, пока Microsfoft их не купила и уже теперь сама пилит и уже в новых VS (во всяком случае в 2015 точно) автоматом есть такой пункт в IDE (если открывать unity solution)