# Unity 5.5.3f1 виснет при попытки работы с проектом версии 5.2.3

Tags: unity3d

Пользовался версией 5.3, так как последняя с поддержкой висты. Сегодня поставил семерку, и последнюю версию 5.5.3f1 Проект на старой версии открывает без проблем, скрипты тоже открывает нормально, ошибок не показывает. Но при попытке запустить проект все сереет (нормальная реакция на кнопку "play"), но на этом все - дальше все зависло. При запуске диспетчера задач загруженность процессора около 90%, и тут же падает до "около" 4%, при этом состояние юнити -  "работает". Ждал несколько минут - ничего не поменялось. Создал новый проект - все запускается нормально. Какие есть варианты, кроме создания нового проекта и переноса туда поштучно всего, что у меня есть?

---

Обновление: теперь при загрузке проекта крашится. Это из лога

```
 d3d11.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module d3d11.dll at 0033:f7392d72.
```

---

Обновление:
Попробовал перенести все со старого проекта на новый поштучно, начал со спрайтов. Скопировал все изображения (без .мета, только картинки) из старого проекта (созданного в старой версии) в новый, созданный только что. И эти изображения в assets выглядят очень странно - какое-то частично смазано, какое-то визуально содержит два спрайта. Оригинальные изображения утеряны после перестановки винды. 
Обновлю все то, что мне подсказали, проверю, что получится. Если не поможет, нарисую новые спрайты (благо у меня черновой вариант на скорую руку "чтоб хоть что-то было"). Если и это не поможет, воспользуюсь способом из первой ссылки из комментария. Ну а там отпишусь

Comment: попробуй убить папки  Library и Temp. возможно в них какая-то мета инфа хранится. не забудь бэкап сделать на всякий

Comment: @АлексейШиманский На первый взгляд, помогло. Смог запустить проект, выключить его, переключить на другую сцену, запустить ее, выключить, переключить обратно на первую сцену, включить ее, выключить... И тут, при переключении на другую сцену, опять все как бы повисло. "Как бы" потому что диспетчер задач настойчиво утверждает, что юнити все же работает

Comment: а сама юнька не замерзла? то есть Play выключается?....... что если пока поставить 5.2.3?

Comment: хм.... [здесь](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13070/getting-the-unity-editor-to-work-in-windows-7-64-b.html) говорят `had to create a DEP exception for Unity. Runs without a hitch now!` .... как это сделать написано [здесь](http://netler.ru/ikt/windows7-dep.htm) .................. а [здесь](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/950569/game-runs-in-editor-crashes-on-startup-after-build.html) еще вариант....... возможно всё же 1 ссылка поможет..... также еще дрова на карту я б посоветовал обновить и directX

Comment: @АлексейШиманский замерзла, вообще ничего не нажимается. Повременю с первым способом, сначала все обновлю. Я и так перешел на 5.5 с 5.6 - та же проблема была, думал, вдруг баг версии. Небольшое обновление - попробовал поштучно перенести спрайты - и с ними что-то странное. Сейчас обновлю основной вопрос

Comment: Если проект запускается без крэша и зависает, то попробуй [поотлаживать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606980/191482)

Comment: `Я и так перешел на 5.5 с 5.6` - я имел в виду не вниз доунгрейдить, а старый проект еще раз попробовать на 5.2.3 загрузить....... что-то из ссылок выше пробовал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Что проверить в первую очередь?

Ну, во-первых, если проект уже был открыт с помощью версии `Unity` поновее, он будет ассоциироваться с версией `Unity` поновее. Так что открывать проект в более старой версии смысла нет.

Также наверняка все файлы проекта уже убиты/как-либо повреждены, если что-то пошло не так. То есть вам нужны абсолютно новые данные из источников (`Google Drive`, `ЯДиск`, `съёмный HDD` и т.д.)
**-** То есть **всё, что есть в проекте**, но **не из папки проекта** (исключение - скрипты и, возможно, модели).

**Но перед этим** можно попробовать применить патч для `Unity`. Патчи выходят стабильно и найти их можно по [ссылке](https://unity3d.com/ru/unity/qa/patch-releases).
**-** Правда обычно они правят баги `физики`, `UI` и т.п.
**-** Каждый **патч имеет список того, что он правит**.
**-** Для вашей версии есть **один патч**.

Если **патч не помог**, то проект нужно **собирать заново из исходных данных** (*Пункт 2*)

## Как избежать этого в дальнейшем?

**Делать бэкап проекта с помощью его экспорта в *`*.unitypackage`* файл**

Вы наверняка видели файлы с таким расширением (пакеты `Asset Store`)

Экспортирование проекта занимает время, пропорциональное размеру проекта, но позволяет безопасно для проделанной работы экспериментировать с версиями, откатить неудачные нововведения и поделиться проектом с коллегами.

**-** К тому же, пакет весит меньше, чем папка с проектом.

**-** А если ***`*.unitypackage`*** засунуть в **архив**, то размер станет ещё меньше (*ваш КО*).

Подробнее о том, как делать импорт и экспорт можно ознакомиться [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html) и [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportpackage.html).

**Использовать систему контроля версий**

Вы также можете использовать систему контроля версий, чтобы работать с вашим проектом. Для этого вам нужно выбрать любой заинтересовавший вас хостинг. Одним из более популярных является `GitHub`. Если же вы хотите бесплатный приватный репозиторий, можете посмотреть в сторону `BitBucket`.

Создав репозиторий, вы сможете держать ваш проект в нескольких вариантах, создавая ветки, и таким образом иметь `stable-версию` проекта и `unstable-версию`, то есть версию проекта, которая подвергается любым изменениям, которые дадут неизвестный результат (от добавления какой-то фичи до миграции на новую версию `Unity`).

Comment: Бэкап, к счастью есть - перед тем, как открыть проект в новой версии, я его копировал. сейчас почитаю про ` *.unitypackage`. Ну а сейчас мне нужно пересобирать проект до тех пор, пока он не будет работать? и каждый раз пересобирать из старой версии проекта? ну и патч щас пробую качать

Comment: @KremSoda обновил ответ. Да, если патч не поможет, то вам придётся собирать проект заново. Именно поэтому при миграции рекомендуется делать бэкапы в *__`*.unitypackage`__*, а потом создавать проекты на новой версии и импортировать в них старый проект через `Assets -> Import -> Custom package` (вроде так, давно с Unity не работаю)

Comment: @KremSoda , Kit Scribe  зачем бэкапы хранить в unitypackage если есть git, svn, mercurial и прочие адекватные вещи

Comment: @АлексейШиманский честно, никогда не пытался проекты совместить с `Git`'ом. Да и нужды в этом не было. А `Git` разве будет хранить модели или текстуры?

Comment: @KitScribe конечно. и модели и текстуры и скрипты и сцены и префабы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда, пожалуй, стоит добавить этот вариант в ответ

Comment: @KremSoda обновил ответ

Comment: Итак, несколько часов продолжаю делать проект, полет нормальный. Помогло что-то из этого (по порядку): обновил дрова на видеокарту, пересобирал проект несколько раз, поставил патч, удача. А может, все сразу. Всем спасибо за помощь)